# How do I include file containing a table of numbers in my swift playground

Tags: swift, include

I want to access a file of numbers in my swift playground.  I'd like to do something like *#include* or *import* but I don't know the syntax.  I see **modules** referenced in *The Swift Programming Language* book but I don't see how to declare, create or use them in the context of a playground.

Is there a mechanism to include an arbitrary file in my playground?

Answer (score 1):

`playground` *file* is a folder and under this folder you can create new folder named: `Resources`. Put your file under `Resources` and you can load it in Playground.

The root URL points to `Resources` so to read file you can write like:

```
let text = String(contentsOfFile: "data.txt", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```

---

*As a side note*

By the same way you can put there images

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to read the file as data, I want to include it as if I had typed it.